# I can't get rid of my own VS code snippet

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Please help, I'm going crazy.
I added a user snippet to help me add opening PHP tags a long time ago. Now, I can't get rid of it. I have uninstalled vs code several times, deleted known vs code folders including the whole %home%\.vscode folder and the %appdata%\roaming\code folder.
I have used advanced installer to clean up program residue files, yet, this snippet appears every time.
The crazy thing is, if I switch to my administrator account, the snippet doesn't exist but I do all my coding on my windows standard user account. It's driving me crazy!!
What do I do?

See screenshot below.
[PHP snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSvpj.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a snippet: [Types of Completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions).

[image]

Comment: how do I remove this keyword? I know I added it because it doesn't exist if I open the editor with another user account.

Comment: Try to run it without extensions (from OS console): "code --disable-extensions"

Comment: Thanks. I found the culprit. It's a bug with the PHP Intellisense extension by Felix Becker. The issue is mentioned here [link](https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/372)